# WordPress or Drupal for building a website that acts like a database but is low-traffic?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, drupal

So, I have an interesting conundrum. I need to build a small website (no more than ten pages). I expect the site to receive low or maybe eventually medium traffic; I'm not expecting thousands of visitors per day or anything like that. One of the pages will basically need to act like a database, displaying hundreds, and potentially thousands, of results. The "database" will need to be searchable and filterable. I'm trying to decide between Drupal and WordPress.

**For Drupal,** the views and exposed filters functionality would give me exactly what I need. But, Drupal seems like overkill for a small site with low traffic. Plus, I'm the only web person in my department, and I worry about having to maintain a Drupal site (which is more difficult than maintaining a WP site) on my own. I could probably make it happen, but I suspect it would eat a lot of time.

**For WordPress,** I would probably need to purchase some sort of faceted search plugin. The free plugins available don't meet the need of the site. My concern is that if the "database" reaches thousands of entries, WordPress will start performing poorly. I've heard that too much content can affect WordPress performance in a way that it doesn't with Drupal. I come from a Drupal background, so I'm not sure whether WP could handle this.

Finally, I'm assuming that each database entry would be entered as a custom post (for WP) or a piece of content on a custom content type (for Drupal) -- so technically the site would have more than ten pages, but the entries don't really need their own page, they just need to show up on the page that is acting like a database. So I'm also wondering if there is a better way to store the data and bring it in to the website another way.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the the other pages like? If it's only supposed to be some static info I'd go for no CMS, or something that can generate static html out of markdown. Then go all in and make the "database" page the way you want/need. It will probably take a bit longer for the development part but you will not need to maintain the CMS, update plugins and all that.

Answer (score 1):

If I was you I would go for Drupal because you already have Drupal background, you know how to implement what you need with Views + Exposed filters whereas things are not so clear with WP. If you reach really large size of the data you could install Search API Solr + Facets on your Drupal website. Since then you may not be bothered by your data capacity anymore.

Maintaining a simple website (and for me it sounds like a simple "site-building" website so far) is not that difficult and time consuming. Just check your modules and core are of the freshest version every now and then.

In case you need to improve your coaching - Memcached plays nice with Drupal out of the box.

P. S. I might be a little bit biased since I have solid Drupal experience including building complex projects and small, quick, "one day" websites. I don't have much experience with WP though. Choose a system you know best.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am leaning toward Drupal for exactly the reasons you specified.